# Can Hibernate automagically populate objects from a stored procedure result set?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations, persistence, resultset

I know that for insert/update/select/delete on a single database row, Hibernate can fetch or persist an object without XML column mappings if the class has appropriately placed annotations for `@Id`, `@Column`, `@Table` etc.

But is that kind of operation possible for a result set returned by a stored procedure, with Hibernate analyzing `ResultSetMetaData` and the annotations to automagically populate each field in an object or collection of objects?  If yes, how is it done?

Does the SQL query for the result set have to be based on a single table, or can it be a table join that returns a mix of columns from multiple tables (I realize I'd have to define an entity object that matches the specific set of columns returned in the query)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if Hibernate does this, but I think the annotations that are used are available at runtime. If you felt ambitious, it shouldn't be too much work to grab the column names and map them to the corresponding fields.

You can use [native SQL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/vasiliev-jpql-087123.html) though in your queries.